# How to download the llama parameters?

Tags: nlp, llama-index

I am working with `pyllama` but had some problems.

I simply do what they said on https://github.com/juncongmoo/pyllama:

```
python -m llama.download --model_size 7B
```

It said

```
❤️ Resume download is supported. You can ctrl-c and rerun the program to resume the downloading
Downloading tokenizer...
✅ pyllama_data/tokenizer.model
✅ pyllama_data/tokenizer_checklist.chk
Downloading 7B
✅ pyllama_data/7B/params.json
✅ pyllama_data/7B/checklist.chk
Checking checksums
```

It didn't download the most import `consolidated.00.pth` file! What have gone wrong? Please help

Answer (score 0):

To download any recent Llama-2 model, the best way is to register to the Meta website:

1. Register your email here: https://ai.meta.com/resources/models-and-libraries/llama-downloads/
2. `git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/llama`
3. `./download.sh`
4. Follow the instruction, especially when needed to paste the link received in the email in the script's prompt